# wp_ajax data_fetch not working if there's a CPT in the array

Tags: ajax, wordpress

If I add the CPTs ('applicazione' and 'miscele') to 'post' and 'page' in the array they are not searched. If I leave just the CPTs it works. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code I am using.

```
// add the ajax fetch js
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'ajax_fetch' );
function ajax_fetch() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function fetch(){
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
    type: 'post',
    data: { action: 'data_fetch', keyword: jQuery('#keyword').val() },
    success: function(data) {
        jQuery('#datafetch').html( data );
    }
});
}
</script>
<?php
}


// the ajax function
add_action('wp_ajax_data_fetch' , 'data_fetch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_data_fetch','data_fetch');
function data_fetch(){

$the_query = new WP_Query( 
  array( 
    'post_type' => array('post','page','applicazione','miscele'),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    's' => esc_attr( $_POST['keyword'] )       
  ) 
);

if( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
    while( $the_query->have_posts() ): $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <h4><a href="<?php echo esc_url( post_permalink() ); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h4>
    <?php endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();  
endif;

die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

The problem was the Polylang plugin. Adding the CPTs to the translation settings fixed the issue.